# Missing SSR support after converting from angular 16 to angular 17

Tags: typescript, server-side-rendering, angular16, angular17

I have upgraded my project from Angular 16 to Angular 17. But, I am currently not receiving support for Server-Side Rendering (SSR). Does Angular provide SSR support after migrating from Angular 16 to Angular 17?

I have created a new Angular 17 project and noticed the presence of main.server.ts, server.ts files, and the @angular/ssr library for Server-Side Rendering (SSR) support. However, when I converted from version 16 to version 17, these components were not automatically generated. Is there a way to generate them automatically without making too many manual changes?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Universal has been mooved to Angular SSR with Angular 17. have a look on [this](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/README.md) about that. That said, you can now use this command to add ssr to your project: `ng add @angular/ssr`. Here is [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ssr) for more details. Seems there is no way (or not yet) to convert make ssr migration for Angular v16 to v17. you have to do it manually.